# Issues with Ubuntu 18.04 linux-firmware package

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I have several Ubuntu 18.04 severs which are stuck on the following:

```
Setting up linux-firmware (1.173.16) ...

update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-88-generic
```

The simulation of installing that package succeeds, however the installation gets stuck:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get update

apt list --upgradable

linux-firmware/bionic-updates 1.173.16 all [upgradable from: 1.173.14]
apt-get --simulate --only-upgrade install linux-firmware
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-firmware
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst linux-firmware [1.173.14] (1.173.16 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf linux-firmware (1.173.16 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
apt-get --only-upgrade install linux-firmware
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-firmware
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 75.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 513 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ee.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 1.173.16 [75.1 MB]
Fetched 75.1 MB in 1s (74.7 MB/s)
(Reading database ... 137216 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-firmware_1.173.16_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (1.173.16) over (1.173.14) ...
Setting up linux-firmware (1.173.16) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-88-generic
```

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue?